# Microsoft Ajax Minifier doesn't shorten my function names

Tags: javascript, c#, microsoft-ajax-minifier

I declare the following javascript

```
window.myApp = {};
myApp.myVeryLongFunctionName = function()
{
    ...
};
```

Then I minify the javascript with the following (in C#)

```
var minifiedCode = minifier.MinifyJavaScript(code, new CodeSettings
{
    RemoveUnneededCode = true,
    PreserveImportantComments = false,
    LocalRenaming = LocalRenaming.CrunchAll,
    EvalTreatment = EvalTreatment.MakeAllSafe,
    OutputMode = OutputMode.SingleLine,
    PreserveFunctionNames = false                        
});
```

But "myApp" and "veryLongFunctionName" doesn't get shorted, it gets minfied to this.

```
window.myApp={};myApp.myVeryLongFunctionName=function(){};
```

I would the code to be minified to something like this.

```
window.a={};a.b=function(){};
```

What code settings parameters do I need to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`MinifyJavaScript()` returns the minified code as a string.  Try this:

```
var s = minifier.MinifyJavaScript(code, new CodeSettings
{
  RemoveUnneededCode = true,
  PreserveImportantComments = false,
  LocalRenaming = LocalRenaming.CrunchAll,
  EvalTreatment = EvalTreatment.MakeAllSafe,
  OutputMode = OutputMode.SingleLine,
  PreserveFunctionNames = false                        
});
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: I know the method returns minfied code. That's not my problem. Clarified the question, thanx for pointing that out.